# Windows 7 File Permissions, Security Tab, "Group or user names" SYSTEM group

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, username, user-groups

*Note: This is a re-posting of a 'too broad' topic. This is a narrowed version:

I right click a file, and choose "Permissions." I choose the "Security" tab. Under the "Group or user names" section, I see the an item called "SYSTEM" (all capitalized). The SYSTEM has all permissions. Can someone explain what this SYSTEM group really means, and what it is for (preferably in detail)

My assumption is that the SYSTEM is the operating system (Windows 7 for me).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Can someone explain what this SYSTEM group really means, and what it is for?

> The system account and the administrator account (Administrators
> group) have the same file privileges, but they have different
> functions.
>
> **The system account is used by the operating system and by services that run under Windows. There are many services and processes within
> Windows that need the capability to log on internally (for example
> during a Windows installation).**
>
> The system account was designed for that purpose; it is an internal
> account, does not show up in User Manager, cannot be added to any
> groups, and cannot have user rights assigned to it. On the other hand,
> the system account does show up on an NTFS volume in File Manager in
> the Permissions portion of the Security menu.
>
> By default, the system account is granted full control to all files on
> an NTFS volume. Here the system account has the same functional
> privileges as the administrator account.
>
> NOTE: Granting either account Administrators group file permissions
> does not implicitly give permission to the system account. The system
> account's permissions can be removed from a file but it is not
> recommended.

Source [How the System account is used in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120929)

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Built-in Users and Default Groups](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-security_groups.html)

---